# I have installed Sharp globally using npm but I can't use it

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, sharp

Whenever I use sharp --version, it shows sharp command not found

```
sharp --version
bash: sharp: command not found
```

I can't use

```
const sharp= require('sharp');
```

It gives error of - "Module not found"

If I use it without requiring it, I get error like- "sharp is not defined"

Comment: `sudo npm uninstall -g sharp` and then `sudo npm i -g sharp`

Answer (score 0):

you need to install it locally `npm install sharp` to be able to require it ,
to be able to install an npm package for a node.js project you need to have package.json file inside that project folder, use `npm init` to create that package.json file,

here an exapmle of using sharp to get information of an image

```
//app.js
const sharp = require("sharp");

async function getMetadata() {
  try {
    const metadata = await sharp("image.png").metadata();
    console.log(metadata);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`An error occurred during processing: ${error}`);
  }
}

getMetadata();
```

run the app

```
node app.js
```

Comment: I did them all but yet still I get some error. So I replaced Sharp with another package called jimp